# single algorithm to work on both directed and undirected graph to detect cycles?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, depth-first-search, directed-graph

I have been trying to implement an algorithm to detect cycles (probably how many of them) in a `directed and undirected graph`. That is the code should apply for both directed and undirected graphs.

Using `DFS or topological sort` is mostly recommended in various posts. But largely, everything is addressed for undirected graph.

[This link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/13.GRAPH.html) describes one approach for cycle detection. To my understanding this works for directed graphs.

[This link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/CC.java.html) has the code for cycle detection in undirected graphs. but I fail to understand how it ignores the back edge. That is it must ignore any cycles with two nodes, say D to C and C to D.
which means it must remember it parent as the DFS recurses. But the code does not seem take care of that.

Any suggestions welcome..

[image]

Comment: Your second link is about detecting **Connected Component**, not about cycles.

Comment: isnt connect component essentially a cycle?

Comment: A cycle is a subgraph of `k` vertices where there are `k` edges connecting the `k` vertices into a single loop. Connected component is an induced subgraph of `k` vertices which is connected. In your graph example, there is only one connected component (the whole graph), and there are three cycles: `A-B-E-A`, `A-B-D-A`, `A-E-B-D-A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some important aspects:
- detecting cycles is usually easier than counting them (since you can have cycles inside another cycle)
- indeed, for directed and undirected graphs the algorithms can be very different (usually, a much more efficient one for the undirected case).

Second, my 2 cents for a general purpose algorithm (cycle counting for directed graph) would be a slightly modified [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_Warshall):

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            A[i][j] += A[i][k] * A[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet assumes that A is the adjacency matrix of your graph and n is the number of nodes. Complexity is O(n^3) obviously.

It will modify the adjacency matrix to contain in each position (i,j) **the number of paths** starting from i and ending with j. In other words, if you are interested in the number of cycles that start with node x, just read A[x][x] (the corresponding number of the main diagonal of the matrix).

The only problem that remains here is if you are interested in a global cycle count. Since I don't have a proof of correctness for the solution I have in mind (and don't have the time to verify it), I won't post any details (sorry).

---

**PS**: For cycle detection (only), there are quicker options available:

- in an undirected graph (easiest case), try looking into the Union find problem ([Disjoint set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-find)). This is one of the fastest non-trivial graph algorithms I know (almost linear with all optimizations in place if I remember correctly).
- in a directed graph, I would use DFS as you mentioned. The second link you mentioned works fine if you put an else for the "if (!marked[v])" in the "dfs" function (as in: else 'a cycle was found').